# Example of populating list in experience profile page with JSON data

Tags: xdb, experience-profile, javascript

I am setting up a custom tab with `custom facet` data in the `Experience Profile`.   I am successfully returning text values to the screen.

Now, I want to populate data into a list control. Are there any examples of this.

In my `AdditionalInfoPanel`, I have a `GenericDataProvider` and a `ListControl`.

**My list has three columns:** for Sent, ContactType, and Message.

**My javascript file looks like this:**

```js
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/DataProviderHelper.js", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/CintelUtl.js"], function (sc, providerHelper, cintelUtil) {
        var app = sc.Definitions.App.extend({
            initialized: function () {
                var localUrl = "/customfields/";
                providerHelper.setupHeaders([
                    { urlKey: localUrl }
                ]);
    
                var url = sc.Contact.baseUrl + localUrl;
                var communicationData;
                var $that = this;
                providerHelper.initProvider(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider, "", url, this.AdditionalInfoTabMessageBar);
                providerHelper.getData(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider,
                    $.proxy(function (jsondata) {
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.CompanyValue, renderUrl(jsondata.Company, jsondata.CompanyUrl), true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.IndustryValue, jsondata.Industry, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.SubIndustryValue, jsondata.SubIndustry, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.RevenueRangeValue, jsondata.RevenueRange, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownExecutiveValue, jsondata.IsKnownExecutive, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownCustomerValue, jsondata.IsKnownCustomer, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownBlogUserValue, jsondata.IsKnownBlogUser, true); /* working correctly */
                        cintelUtil.setText($that.OptInValue, jsondata.OptIn, true); /* working correctly */
                        communicationData = JSON.stringify(jsondata.Communications);
                        console.log(communicationData); /* SEE NOTE 1 FOR THIS OUTPUT */
                        providerHelper.initProvider(this.AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataProvider, "", url, this.AdditionalInfoCommunicationMessageBar);
                        providerHelper.getListData(this.AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataProvider, communicationData); /* SEE NOTE 2 FOR ERROR */
                    }));
            }
        });
    
        function renderUrl(text, url) {
            if (url !== null && url.length > 0)
            {
                return "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + text + "</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                return text;
            }
        }
    
        return app;
    });
```

**NOTE 1:** The output of this console.log is:

```
[{"Sent":"2016-10-18T17:25:36.831Z","ContactType":"Product Information","Message":"Looking to get information about software","IsEmpty":false}]
```

**NOTE 2:** The resulting error is:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined / DataProviderHelper.js:74
```

I am trying to figure out how to correctly bind the data in `jsondata.Communications` to the ListControl.

I am using `Sitecore 8.1 Update 2`

---

**UPDATE 1:** Using suggested changes below... this is my JavasScript:

```js
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/DataProviderHelper.js", "/-/speak/v1/experienceprofile/CintelUtl.js"], function (sc, providerHelper, cintelUtil) {
    var app = sc.Definitions.App.extend({
        initialized: function () {
            var localUrl = "/customfields/";
            providerHelper.setupHeaders([
                { urlKey: localUrl }
            ]);

            var url = sc.Contact.baseUrl + localUrl;
            var communicationData;
            var $that = this;
            providerHelper.initProvider(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider, "", url, this.AdditionalInfoTabMessageBar);
            providerHelper.getData(this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider,
                $.proxy(function (jsondata) {
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.CompanyValue, renderUrl(jsondata.Company, jsondata.CompanyUrl), true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.IndustryValue, jsondata.Industry, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.SubIndustryValue, jsondata.SubIndustry, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.RevenueRangeValue, jsondata.RevenueRange, true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownExecutiveValue, convertBooleanToYesNo(jsondata.IsKnownExecutive), true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownCustomerValue, convertBooleanToYesNo(jsondata.IsKnownCustomer), true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownBlogUserValue, convertBooleanToYesNo(jsondata.IsKnownBlogUser), true);
                    cintelUtil.setText($that.OptInValue, convertBooleanToYesNo(jsondata.OptIn), true);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata.Communications));
                    $that.AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataSource.set('items', jsondata.Communications);
                }));
        }
    });

    function renderUrl(text, url) {
        if (url !== null && url.length > 1) {
            return "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + text + "</a>";
        }
        else {
            return text;
        }
    }

    function convertBooleanToYesNo(value) {
        if (value == 'true' || value == true) {
            return 'Yes';
        }
        else if (value == 'false' || value == false) {
            return 'No';
        }
        else {
            return value;
        }
    }

    return app;
});
```

Here you can see the Renderings of my panel:
[image: Renderings]

Here you can see my List binding:
[image: List binding]

Here you can see a couple of my Column Fields:
[image: Column fields]

I no longer get an error, but the 'Communications' data is still not loaded in the grid. :-(  Any ideas?

---

**CLOSING UPDATE**

@gorhal had the solution.  One further step was to ensure the "Items" property of the ListControl was bound to the datasource items: `{Binding AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataSource.Items}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use a `SearchDataSource` and then bind it to your `ListControl`.

Check this post for binding example:
https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/put-json-data-in-your-searchdatasource-and-bind-it-to-searchabledroplist-sitecore-speak/

Now, in your code, if you do this (`jsondata.Communications` needs to be an array):

```js
providerHelper.getData(
    this.AdditionalInfoDataProvider,
    $.proxy(function (jsondata) {
        cintelUtil.setText($that.CompanyValue, renderUrl(jsondata.Company, jsondata.CompanyUrl), true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.IndustryValue, jsondata.Industry, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.SubIndustryValue, jsondata.SubIndustry, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.RevenueRangeValue, jsondata.RevenueRange, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownExecutiveValue, jsondata.IsKnownExecutive, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownCustomerValue, jsondata.IsKnownCustomer, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.IsKnownBlogUserValue, jsondata.IsKnownBlogUser, true); /* working correctly */
        cintelUtil.setText($that.OptInValue, jsondata.OptIn, true); /* working correctly */

        $that.YourSearchDataSource.set('items', jsondata.Communications);

        providerHelper.initProvider(this.AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataProvider, "", url, this.AdditionalInfoCommunicationMessageBar);
    }));
```

Since this is SPEAK version 1 (using set) I think you should do this:

```js
$that.YourSearchDataSource.set('items', jsondata.Communications);
```

SPEAK2 is so much cleaner, so you can use this:

```js
$that.YourSearchDataSource.Items = jsondata.Communications;
```

You will also need to create column definitions for the list control; here is an example from the `LatestVisitors` list on the dashboard in the Experience Profile:

[image: LatestVisitors list]

Then you will need to create a `Columnfield` for each column:
Sent, ContactType, and Message

Don't forget to enter the JSON field name (from the JSON array) in the `DataField` on the `Columnfield`:

[image: Columnfield]

Finally, go to your layout and select your list control to get its properties. Locate the `DataSource` attribute and point it to your new `ColumnDefinitions` item:

[image: Speak layout]

That should be it, I hope it will help you :-)

Comment: See my update above.   No more errors, but still no data.

Comment: Could you please show how the  jsondata.Communications look like? Not all but parts of it

Comment: [{"Sent":"2016-10-18T17:25:36.831Z","ContactType":"Product Information","Message":"Looking to get information about software","IsEmpty":false}]

Comment: Hmm... If you would create an array like this:
var myArray = [];
var myElement = {};
myElement["Sent"] = "2016-10-18T17:25:36.831Z";
myElement["ContactType"] = "Product Information";
myElement["Message"] = ""Looking to get information about software";
myElement["IsEmpty"] = false;

myArray.push(myElement);

And then set that one instead of jsondata.Communications to the DataSource. Will you still have an empty list? By the way does the list show the column names or is it just empty

Comment: Column names appear, just no data.

Comment: I tried changing the last line(s) to `var myArray = []; var myElement = {}; myElement["Sent"] = "2016-10-18T17:25:36.831Z"; myElement["ContactType"] = "Product Information"; myElement["Message"] = "Looking to get information about software"; myElement["IsEmpty"] = false; myArray.push(myElement); 
     $that.AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataSource.set('items', myArray);`  But it has the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm. Did you bind the datasource to the listcontrol, I can't see that in your screendumps. You should have an Items property on the listcontrol:
{Binding AdditionalInfoCommunicationDataSource.Items}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47139/discussion-between-gorhal-and-eat-sleep-code).

Comment: This was the solution -- see "Closing Update" on the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find your answer in [this blog from Jonathan Robbins](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/).

It is quite some code - too much to copy here.
An overview of what is all in his example:

- SubPageCode rendering
- The `Border` rendering adds a Placeholder for the other renderings.
- The `MessageBar` is used to display messages
- `AdvancedExpander` datasources the `SampleOrdersAccordion` Item we created earlier. The next four renderings are added to this AdvancedExpander‘s placeholder.
- The `ListControl` is responsible for displaying the data

  - Set the `Datasource` the `SampleOrders ListControl` item
  - Items field looks at the data provider to know what to display e.g. `{Binding SampleOrdersDataProvider.cidata}`.
- `ProgressIndicator` displays a loading indicator for the `ListControl`

  - Set it’s `Target` property to the `Id` of the `ListControl`
  - `IsBusy` property is wired to the following `GenericDataProvider` e.g. `{Binding SampleOrdersDataProvider.IsBusy}`
  - Finally it datasourced to the out-of-the-box `ProgressIndicator` Item.
- `GenericDataProvider` actually holds the data we are loading and displaying. Datasourced to an Item called `DataProviderForListControl` – `{6CD06869-4264-420C-A161-3220DD3AB7BA}`
- `Border` adds a placeholder for a ‘see more’ button is more data is available than the page size.

  - To set this conditional visibility set the `IsVisible` field to a property of the `DataProvider` denoting if there is more data available than the page – `{Binding SampleOrdersDataProvider.HasMoreData}`
- The `Button` facilitates pagination of the data, its `Click` event field set to a preexisting JavaScript Method – `javascript:app.SampleOrdersDataProvider.nextListData()`.

His result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I am already pretty much where this example shows, what I am missing is that his appears to be pulling data from some table.   I need to pull mine from the jsondata that would be returned for the contact.